# laravel Pluck() returns a single row not collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, laravel

i an developing a drop-down and for that I need a json format in key values that's why i used pluck() helper function but it is not working accurately it returns a single row
when i tried to Querylog the following query it shows it should not show limit() because i am not using it.

Controller

```
{
    DB::enableQueryLog();
    $sections = DB::table("sections")->where("division_id",$request->division)->pluck("name","id");

    dd(DB::getQueryLog());

    return response()->json($sections);
}
```

Because i used pluck the following query is actually running

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "query" => "select `name` from `sections` where `division_id` = ? limit 1"
    "bindings" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "1"
    ]
    "time" => 0.0
  ]
]
```

whereas i need the result in JSON key value pair so i can use it in the following java-script

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#division').change(function(){
    var divisionID = $(this).val();    
    if(divisionID){
        $.ajax({
           type:"GET",
           dataType: "json",
           url:"{{url('get-section-list')}}?division="+divisionID,
           success:function(res){               
            if(res){

                $("#section").empty();
                $("#section").append('<option>Select</option>');
                $.each(res,function(key,value){
                    $("#section").append('<option value="'+key+'">'+value+'</option>');
                });

            }else{
               $("#section").empty();
            }
           }
        });
    }else{
        $("#section").empty();

    }      
   });
</script>
```

Comment: You're using `value` not `pluck`, they are two different things.

Comment: pluck also shows the same result. i tried before but mistakenly upload value code

Comment: ```->pluck('name', 'id')->get()``` I could be mistaken, but I recall running get() after I pluck()

Comment: get() after pluck() can't be used pluck cannot used on array but on collection

Comment: Then how about using get before pluck .....

Comment: `$query->pluck('name', 'id')` shoud returns a collection with `id` keys and `name` values you don't need `get()`, if you use `get()->pluck()` you are using the collection `pluck()` not the query builder `pluck()`. What version of laravel?

Comment: Your query log shows that you were using `$query->value('name')` and not `$query->pluck('name', 'id')` there is no `LIMIT 1` in a `pluck()` SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In controller

```
//should just make a model for sections then you could just do:
// return Section::select('name', 'id')->where("division_id",$request->division)->get();

//controller will output it as json by default
return DB::table("sections")->select('name', 'id')->where("division_id",$request->division)->get();
```

view:

//you dont need a key value object just loop over results and reference it by property as shown below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#division').change(function(){
    var divisionID = $(this).val();    
    if(divisionID){
        $.ajax({
           type:"GET",
           dataType: "json",
           url:"{{url('get-section-list')}}?division="+divisionID,
           success:function(res){               
            if(res){

                $("#section").empty();
                $("#section").append('<option>Select</option>');
                $.each(res,function(placement,row){
                    $("#section").append('<option value="'+row.id+'">'+row.name+'</option>');
                });

            }else{
               $("#section").empty();
            }
           }
        });
    }else{
        $("#section").empty();

    }      
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Well i tried this because pluck() wasn;t working and i need JSON in key value so first i get the array converted it in collection then applied pluck()

```
public function getSectionList(Request $request)
{
DB::enableQueryLog();

$sections = DB::table("sections")
            ->select('name', 'id')
            ->where("division_id",$request->division)->get();

$collection = collect($sections);
$sectoion_list =  $collection->pluck('name', 'id');


return response()->json($sectoion_list);
```

}

Comment: If this is not an answer, I suggest you remove this and edit your original question with the new information -- makes it easier to help you.

Comment: `$query->pluck()` is working fine, you don't need to retrieve the collection and do the pluck() on it. If your results are real you should open an issue to the laravel repo.